# Why my image is not readable after uploaded on the Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am newbie on Django and I would like to implement a request that allow to make upload file.
I wrote some code for this, but when I opened the file in local, my computer says it may be damaged.
I don't understand why because the size file is the same to another when i sent with postman.

here is my code :

view.py

```
 def handle_uploaded_file(f):
     with open(f.name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)


 class FileUploadView(APIView):
     parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

     def put(self, request, filename, format="png"):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        handle_uploaded_file(file_obj)
        return Response(filename, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're writing the files into the system manually but Django already has a way to handle the uploading of files - and DRF just builds on top of that. All you have to do is create a model with a [`FileField` or any field that extends from it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.FileField).

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    user_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='path/to/upload')
```

Bear in mind that the database does **not** store the file - it only stores the **path to the file**. The file is directly uploaded to the path you've specified in the field. More info about `upload_to` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

To upload using DRF - all you have to do is create a serializer using [`ModelSerializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) and use a generic API view like [`CreateAPIView`](http://www.cdrf.co/3.6/rest_framework.generics/CreateAPIView.html) unless you have other requirements.

Your ModelSerializer can be something like:

```
class UploadFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload  # reference the model above
        fields = '__all__'
```

And in your views:

```
class UploadFileView(CreateAPIView):
     serializer_class = UploadFileSerializer

     def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, files=request.FILES) # <------ note the request.FILES
         serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
         self.perform_create(serializer)
         headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
         return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get this response "No file was submitted."

Comment: My bad, i forgot about including request.FILES. You have to overwrite the create method. Pls see my updated answer

Comment: I try it this code and I get a error with files variable. I changed with file_obj and when I did this I get error 500

Comment: hey there I think there was a typo in the code. The part should be `files = request.FILES` not `files,request.FILES`. the comma should be an equals sign. my apologies for that typo

Comment: The prototype of the function it doesn't match with the DRF prototype get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=None, many=False, partial=False), once again thank you